# Why are those two "auto boxing" statements giving different results?

Tags: objective-c

Looking at the following, why is c_obj not of class __NSCFBoolean even though b_obj is?  The only difference between b and c is the negation operator.  I

```
BOOL a = ![[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] boolValue];
id a_obj = @(a);
NSLog(@"a_obj class: %@", [a_obj class]); // class is __NSCFBoolean

// This one behaves the same as a
id b_obj = @([[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] boolValue]);
NSLog(@"b_obj class: %@", [b_obj class]); // class is __NSCFBoolean

// But not this one, even though it is pretty much the same
id c_obj = @(![[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] boolValue]);
NSLog(@"c_obj class: %@", [c_obj class]); // class is __NSCFNumber ?!?
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT :

If I cast to BOOL, it fixes the issue.

```
// A cast "fixes" it
id d_obj = @((BOOL)![[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] boolValue]);
NSLog(@"d_obj class: %@", [d_obj class]); // class is __NSCFBoolean
```

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I can tell you that you shouldn't really care. When dealing with `NSNumber`s, you have no guarantees at all whatsoever. From the docs: "Note that number objects do not necessarily preserve the type they are created with". And `@()` is nothing else but a shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWith...]`!

Comment: http://nshipster.com/bool/

Comment: The source of my confusion was that while serializing a dictionary to json, I would get "yes" int the string when the value was true and 0 when it was false, confused the hell out of me.  Ken Thomases answer makes it quite obvious, the negation operator returns an int; which when not cast gets auto boxed to an NSCFNumber...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the logical negation operator (`!`) is `int` in (Objective-)C. Since that's a different type than `BOOL`, it's not terribly surprising that the compiler boxes it differently.